# Powershell add folder name as suffix to files recursively only if folder name matches string

Tags: powershell

How can I get this script modified to do the following:

1. Recurse through the entire specified directory
2. Find folders with a specified name (can be many folders through the directory)
3. For each file inside of each folder append the folder name as suffix

This is what I managed to find/try so far; however, this code adds the suffix to all the files it finds no matter what folder they are located at.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\0\DG\a/" -Include *.* -Recurse | Where {$_.Name -notlike "$($_.Directory.Name)*"} | ForEach-Object {
    $NewName = $_.Basename + '-' + $_.Directory.Name + $_.Extension
    If (!(Test-Path "$($_.DirectoryName)\$NewName" -PathType Leaf)) {Rename-Item -Path "$($_.FullName)" -NewName $NewName}
    Else {Write-Warning "Could not rename '$($_.Name)' as '$($_.DirectoryName)\$NewName' already exists!"}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the specified directory name? Why are you mixing path separators, _(`C:\0\DG\a/`)_?

Comment: @Compo, honestly it is a typo. the folder name we can call it/them HASS, MR3A, OLB4... the name can be anything since I might have tons of folders in the end. I figured it was easier to handle one or a few at time versus me specifying the conversome folder structure I'm dealing with.. thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* what you are looking for is something like this:

```
$sourceFolder   = "C:\0\DG\a"
$folderToSearch = 'TheSpecificFolderName'
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "$folderToSearch*"} | ForEach-Object {
    $folder = $_.FullName
    foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File)) {
        $NewName = '{0}-{1}{2}' -f $file.BaseName, $file.Directory.Name, $file.Extension
        $target  = Join-Path -Path $folder -ChildPath $NewName
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $target -PathType Leaf)) {
            $file | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "Could not rename '$($file.Name)' as '$NewName' already exists!"
        }
    }
}
```

If the "specified directory name" which as you say *can be many folders through the directory* is an **array** of folder names, change to this:

```
$sourceFolder    = "C:\0\DG\a"
$foldersToSearch = 'FirstSpecificFolderName', 'SecondSpecificFolderName', 'ThirdSpecificFolderName'

# create a regex string where the foldernames to look for are combined with regex OR (`|`)
# use [regex]::Escape() to escape any characters that have special meaning in regex.
# the "^" anchors the match at the beginning of the string.
$findThese = '^({0})' -f (($foldersToSearch | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|')

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $findThese} | ForEach-Object {
    $folder = $_.FullName
    foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File)) {
        $NewName = '{0}-{1}{2}' -f $file.BaseName, $file.Directory.Name, $file.Extension
        $target  = Join-Path -Path $folder -ChildPath $NewName
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $target -PathType Leaf)) {
            $file | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "Could not rename '$($file.Name)' as '$NewName' already exists!"
        }
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, I have added the `-WhatIf` switch to the `Rename-Item` cmdlet. This wil not actually rename any files, but show you in the console what *WOULD* be renamed. If you are happy with that, remove the `-WhatIf` switch.

Comment: @samgoto Thanks for the nice feedback!